# Performing regression analysis between two variables using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, ndvi, regression

I have a temperature image (interpolated from climatic point data) and NDVI data at the monthly interval.

I need to do correlation analysis between temp and NDVI.

Is it impossible to do this using ArcGIS Desktop, and if so, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: are you looking to do a spatial correlation (spatial autocorrelation) or a regression analysis?

Answer (score 10):

**It is usually a mistake to estimate correlations between grids when one or both have been interpolated**: the estimate often reflects the interpolation method rather than the data themselves.  Moreover, you will *always* grossly over-represent the degrees of freedom, typically leading to falsely high estimates of confidence and precision.

When one dataset is a grid of *measurements,* or derived from measurements (as NDVI is) and the other is a point dataset, it's both better and simpler to extract the grid values at the point locations, forming an (x,y) dataset.  In this case *x* would be the temperature at one of the points where temperature actually is observed and *y* would be the NDVI value at that same location.  There will therefore be one (x,y) datum for each temperature datum available to you.

ArcGIS is not the software to perform a rigorous analysis of an (x,y) dataset: as @Mike Toews suggests, use statistical software.  There are [Web apps](http://statpages.org/#Regression) that will compute correlations, perform ordinary least squares regression, draw scatterplots, and give you confidence intervals for the parameters.  Even [handheld calculators](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~meyer/math141/TI83.html) will do this...  In general, though, for anything except self-instruction, you're best off using well-tested software such as [`R`](http://cran.r-project.org/) or a commercial statistics package.

Comment: GeoDa is a good, simple, geographical statistics package that would do this nicely for you.

Comment: @ChrisStrother but one of the main dis-advantage of geodata is it does not support raster datasets

Comment: @whuber How about if the interpolated surfaces have consistent parameters used in creating them, just the underlying variables in the point dataset has changed (e.g. different time period)?

Comment: @Simon It hinges on what you mean by "consistent parameters." Consider two IDW grids where only the values at the data points (but not their locations) have changed from x_i to y_i, i=1,2,...,n. That gives three "correlations": the true underlying correlation between the grids; the correlation coefficient of the data (x_i,y_i); and the correlation coefficient computed from paired grid cells. The latter are data of the form (A_jx,A_jy) where A_j is the coefficient vector at cell j. *Those data are highly interdependent and redundant.* **At best**, using them would overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure your rasters have the same shape (rows×cols; bounds). You can perform a multivariate [regression analysis](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Regression_analysis) with the Spatial Analyst extension for ArcGIS. I'd start with this approach.

If you want to get really fine-tuned/serious, you can read both data sets into [R](http://www.r-project.org/) (via [rgdal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/)), then perform a suite of statistics on the co-located grid locations or rows of a combined SpatialPixelsDataFrame/data.frame object (e.g. [GLM](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html), [ANOVA](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/anova.lm.html), etc.). This approach will confuse most people, so I would only go in this direction if you are brave or curious.